# SUMIFS with "AND" not "OR"

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

How can I make the SUMIFS more complex, to only SUM the negative numbers from A2:A4 ? (**AND** not to include the lines with "foo" string in the B column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUMIFS(A:A; B:B; "<>foo"; A:A; "<0")
```

Or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A:A; B:B<>"foo"; A:A<0)
```

North American users should replace semi-colons **`;`** with commas **`,`**

Comment: my god THANKS! :) FTW @Blindspots! :)